# Splitting Sections off an Object

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I'm trying to make a simple 3D house with doors, roof, and stairs, I made all of it from the same cube so it would all line up perfectly-ish.

My trouble is I have no idea how to remove sections of it from the block so I can set the material and textures how I'd like.

So for instance, I want to make the doors out of wood, and not have the entire house look like a door.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign material to part of mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/assign-material-to-part-of-mesh)

Comment: When you do get it split up and start animating doors etc, you might find this useful when you come to move the entire house around the scene, rotate it, etc.  The separated components will want to stay behind.  -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166114/partial-rotation/166148#166148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to assign multiple Materials to the same Mesh or how to split one Object into two.

If you just want to Split a Mesh into two, the easiest way is to select all faces you need, hit "P" and then click "By Selection".

To create a 2. Material go to the Materials Tab and hit the "+" icon. Select all  the faces you want to share this Material and then hit "Assign" in the Materials Tab.

[image: Material]